# Storing places in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm projecting to develop an app that allows users to add places on a map and share them.
I've been looking for a solution inside Google Maps but I couldn't understand if there is a way to some how use Google Maps itself to store the data, or some other Google Service.
Do Google Maps API allow to store, and and remove a list of places, or should I get my own cloud storage solution to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place) in Google Maps Places API for Android.

You will learn here that you can use the Google Places API for Android to add a place to Google's Places database. The newly-added place is available to your app after a short time, and is added to a moderation queue for possible addition to Google's Places database and Google Maps.

To add a place, call [`GeoDataApi.addPlace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html), passing an [`AddPlaceRequest`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AddPlaceRequest) object that specifies the details of the place you want to add.

You can check in this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place#add-place) the information that you need to know when adding places.

> Take NOTE that Newly-added places enter a moderation queue to be
>   considered for addition to the Google Places database. Places that are
>   not accepted by the moderation process will continue to be retrievable
>   through the place ID in the app that submitted them, but will no
>   longer appear in the results of get-current-place requests, the api
>   picker, or any other API method. Places that pass moderation will be
>   visible to all apps and on Google Maps.

For more information, check this [Place Add for web services](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place). It is more detailed than the Android documentation.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for a way to add temporary and very dynamic information. Currently I've gone with a separate Baas service, obviously I don't know if it's the optimal solution.